# Track User Session in Wildfly Application Server to a DB session

Tags: oracle, session, wildfly, session-cookies, jmx

Let's take a basic web application architecture , i.e Client <=> Web Server <=> App Server <=> DB

There are many cases when we need to trace user activity end to end across the application. Eg: Which user session corresponds to a poorly running query in DB ? etc

We have a clear means of getting session data in database (v$session for our (or any) Oracle DB). If we go back all the way to the Client-side we have cookies which we are tracking via M&A tool (Dynatrace) as well as the user-ids are tracked in web-server and app-server logs.

However I am unable to make a connection between a DB session record and a specific user http session because all sessions in DB are tagged with the same application user id (Wildfly user id used to establish the datasource connection).

Could you please help how this connection can be made so that entire user journey can be traced ?

I have tried checking the jmx console for an mbean that can give this information but could not find one. The table v$sql_bind_capture provides bind variable data. If we are lucky some of the bind variables can be used to indicate a single user [variables such as userid (or) location if used], but is not a sure fire way of tracking all users.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If you have access to the client application code you can set information in the client allowing you to link a session to a specific client machine. Oh but this assumes client server connection & may not work for web since you might have pooled connections.

You can use **DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO** package and the **SET_MODULE** function at any time in the client. Then you can see this information when looking at the Oracle session info. Check the documentation for the size of those fields, the first one is around 64 characters, and action is pretty short.

```
-- Set Connection Info on Client
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE( 
  'app_name_v1.2.3.4 3rd floor, office 212', 
  'Opened the main window'); 

-- Clear out connection info on Client (not necessary)
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your architecture the App server is the only component having all information to track a whole journey. The database should be treated like a storage that has no clue about the context.
I usually use a use MessageDiagnosticContext (MDC) to provide the context information from the web client layer down to the Appliation server layer to log such journey. If that is not enough you could setup something like logstash to gather all information from all components.